# Get size in bytes of document in aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I know about `Object.bsonsize()` but I'm not sure it'll work in my case. I'm wanting to efficiently figure out which users on my app have the most total data, and I have an aggregation pipeline that uses `$lookup` to collect all of the user's documents (scattered through 3 other collections) together. I then want a pipeline stage that looks something like:

```
$project: {
    "_id": 1,
    "username": 1, 
    "sizeInBytes": {
        $sizeInBytes: ...
    }
}
```

I'm pretty new to aggregation, so not actually sure what I'd want after sizeInBytes, to reference the whole document not just a property.

It looks like maybe in MongoDB 4.0+, this could be done using `$toString` and then `$strLenBytes` but I'm surprised I can't find a built-in way to do this much more directly. (And unfortunately I'm stuck on 3.6 atm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly even with MongoDB 4.0+, it is very messy to calculate size, as you speculated, `String` length can be used. There is [an open ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-33582) pending for a possible future feature within the aggregate pipeline.

With what you have, I suggest using Javascript on the result of your `$lookup` result.

Something like this for example;

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "doc1",
      localField: "userId",
      foreignField: "userId",
      as: "doc1arr"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "doc2",
      localField: "userId",
      foreignField: "userId",
      as: "doc2arr"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "doc3",
      localField: "userId",
      foreignField: "userId",
      as: "doc3arr"
    }
  }
]).map(perUserData => ({ userId: perUserData.userId, size: Object.bsonsize(perUserData) }));
```

will give out something like;

```
[
    {
        "userId" : 1,
        "size" : 250
    },
    {
        "userId" : 2,
        "size" : 350
    }
]
```

See the non-js part on [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1tRuNrcp9B-)

Comment: Ugh, weird. Well, I'm not about to load a gigabyte of data into RAM just to count it. Fortunately I don't actually *need* to do this, I was mostly just curious to find out which user had the most data. Pretty easy to just check the few that are top by object count, I guess.

Comment: @MalcolmOcean yeah, I agree, it is very annoying to use JS within MongoDB, but the lack of feature forces us to do so in such cases... For the object count in `docXarr` fields, of course you can use the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/)

Comment: Why my mongoose show 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'calculateObjectSize' of undefined' ?

Comment: Just for reference, this feature is now available 